# Retrieve info from a query where table name and value are parameters SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to retrieve a bunch of info from SQL procedure. It should receive two parameters, one of the parameters is a table name and the other is the value properly. Is there any way to retrieve that?

This is the query I've created so far:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_Positions_Filtered
    @Parameter VARCHAR(200), 
    @Id VARCHAR(50)
AS
    SELECT 
        POSITION.*, 
        COALESCE((SELECT Category.Name 
                  FROM Category 
                  WHERE Category.Id = POSITION.Area), POSITION.Area) AS AreaName, 
        COALESCE((SELECT Country.Name 
                  FROM Country 
                  WHERE Country.Id = POSITION.Country), POSITION.Country) AS CountryName,
        COALESCE((SELECT Department.Name 
                  FROM Department 
                  WHERE Department.Id = POSITION.Department), POSITION.Department) AS DepartmentName,
        COALESCE((SELECT City.Name 
                  FROM City 
                  WHERE City.Id = POSITION.City), POSITION.City) AS CityName,
        COALESCE((SELECT Salary.Data_Range 
                  FROM Salary  
                  WHERE Salary.Id = POSITION.Wage), POSITION.Wage) AS SalaryRange
    FROM 
        POSITION
    WHERE
        (SELECT DISTINCT name FROM sys.columns WHERE name = @Parameter) = @Id
```

Could somebody help me out with this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You really should not be using the SP_ prefix. It can cause issues. Better to find a different prefix, or even better no prefix at all. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix Also, positions is misspelled. :)

Comment: For the task at hand...it is not at all clear what you are trying to do here. And I would highly recommend using joins instead of all these subqueries to the same table over and over. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using the Dynamic query inside the store procedure. 
see example below:

`CREATE Procedure FC_Sample

@TableName Varchar (100)
AS
BEGIN 
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX);
set @query = 'SELECT * from' + ' ' + @TableName
EXECUTE sp_executesql @query
END`

And you can execute the Stored procedure as below:

`EXEC FC_Sample 'ACIChemical'`

Hope this is what you are looking for.

NOTE: I am giving it in the Answer section as i don't have 50 reputation to comment on this question else i would have asked more question before posting the answer.